# How to Load an Image object in Java

Tags: java, image, user-interface, io

I am getting `input==null` while trying to load an `Image`. I can't seem to figure out why, even after browsing a good number of StackOverflow questions. It looks right to me.

Here is the code:

```
private BufferedImage image;

public practice(){
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    timeBall.start();


    JPanel panelNorth = makePanel();
    panelNorth.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    add(panelNorth, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    try{
         image = ImageIO.read(practice.class.getResource("/pics/flying.png"));

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }






}
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return image == null ? new Dimension(400, 300): new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);     

    ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double(Ox, Oy+Speedy, height, height);
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D)g;
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);           
    graphics.fill(ellipse);
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    

    repaint();
    Oy = Oy + Speedy / 10;
    Ox = Ox + Speedx / 10;
}
```

Comment: `/pics/flying.png` is not available via the CLASSPATH. Where exactly is in your JAR file?

Comment: @EJP I am new to putting images in Java so I don't know what JAR file is, but I created a new source folder and named it pics. That's where the png file is.

Comment: Well you need to learn how to make it so.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864267/load-icon-image-exception

Comment: @Pshemo that's what I used originally, but it still isn't working.

Comment: @EJP I can do that, but can you help me afterwards?

Comment: To get better help you need to provide enough information to allow us reproduce your problem. How do you execute your code? Is it JAR or is it project in your IDE? What IDE are you using? Where is file you are trying to read located in your project?

Comment: I am using an IDE, Eclipse. The file is in a new source folder I created called pics. @Pshemo

Comment: Is the *source folder* called `pics` or does it *contain* folder called `pics`? Notice that source folder is not part of path, it just contains other resources which we should be able to access.

Comment: Then the path is `/flying.png`  Look in your built jar (zip format), or in the build/target/dist folder under classes.

Comment: Creating the JAR did it. Thanks to everyone for the help. I've never done that before.